# Web API Request.Content truncating first 3 characters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-web-api

We are getting empty model object in Post action in Web API ( Even client is sending valid json).

When we try to log content using `Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;` in Custom attribute `[System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute]` we have received valid json

```
Ex:{prop1:"value1",prop2:"val2" }
```

But in below action we are getting invalid request. When we try to log content

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("submitRequest")]
public IHttpActionResult SubmitRequest([FromBody]Test request)
{
   string str = Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result; 
  // We got prop1:"value1",prop2:"val2" }   output 
}
```

Here "{" is missing (in Json) the content as a result model binding is failing.

Can any one help why we are getting inValid Json in action. We have configured following media formator

```
config.Formatters.Add(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());         
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();

[DataContract]
public class Test
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Prop3 { get; set; }
}
```

Can any one help , why we are getting invalid json in action

Comment: The model binding has already read the content stream, so you should seek the begining of the stream before trying to read it again :
`var stream = Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result;
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                string str = reader.ReadToEnd();`
Also in your exemple the json is not valid, it should be : `{"prop1":"value1","prop2":"val2" }`

Comment: There is typo error in example , looks like model binding is failed to deserialize json . i am getting all property in request is null ( request.Prop1 = null .......). Do we need to implement custom binding here

Comment: If you seek the begining of the stream do you still have missing characters at the start of the content? If not try deserializing it : `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Test>(str);`
I think there might be an error in your json and that's why the model binder fails to deserialize it.

Comment: I am able to deserialize Object , but i am expecting model binder to deserialize  the requested Json.  i am getting  request.Prop1 = null ....  [IHttpActionResult SubmitRequest([FromBody]Test request)]

Comment: Check that Request.Content.Headers.ContentType.MediaType is "application/json" without that the model binder might not use the right deserializer

Comment: Thanks J.Loscos !!  This helped . we are setting the Content-Type: application/json in request header (in Rest client),  when we bypass the request from proxy we have same Content-Type: application/json , But if the request come through proxy we are getting Content-Type: text/json which is causing model binding failure